# PHP Mail not showing HTML on Windows PC

Tags: php, html-email

I am sending emails using PHP Mail and they show beautifully on a Mac but do not work on a PC they just show the HTML code in text format.

The current headers I am using are;

```
MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n
```

Is there anything else that I need to add?

Comment: add properly \r\n to your code these are cause of error

Comment: Operating systems do not deal with email, email clients do. I presume you are comparing mac mail with some version of outlook, but really you need to do a lot more testing. How does it look in popular webmail clients (gmail, outlook.com, etc), how about different outlook versions? More than likely the problem is with the particular client, rather than your code

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you change \r\n to just \n this solves the problem, however you do need to do this with every header in the construction of the php mail function.